# Interesting memory values

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I wrote a code, wich uses a huge amount of memory, so I'm monitoring it to the output.
The result is kinda interesting, can someone explain me why is my free memory lowers and than increases, though I'm allocating object continuously, and why does it stack at a value?

Here's my monitoring code:

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                System.out.println("" + (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FaAlgoritmus.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    th.start();
```

And the result:

> 42454
>   49666
>   109869
>   76995
>   39779
>   125981
>   89814
>   191056
>   137835
>   142766
>   121279
>   50221
>   130072
>   75460
>   143199
>   88164
>   145557
>   75224
>   27234
>   136953
>   87933
>   34991
>   151526
>   99113
>   47005
>   163787
>   56278
>   44491
>   44491
>   44491
>   44491
>   44491
>   44491
>   44491
>   44491
>   44491
>   44489
>   44489
>   44489

Comment: Without knowing more about the rest of your code, there's not much that can be said...

Comment: 44 MB is not a huge amount of mem. As for the question, please read about Java memory management here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can someone xplain me why is my free mem lowers and than increases

New objects are allocated in the Eden space. Once you run out of Eden space, a minor garbage collector kicks in and gets rid of unreferenced objects (promoting all referenced objects into one of the survivor spaces). Typically, this would lead to a jump in the amount of free memory.

Comment: I see, and what about the stucked value? It stucks for a value for about 10 times, then stcuk at an other.

Comment: @FerencDajka: I'd recommend using a memory profiler (such as VisualVM or YourKit) to gain further insight.